# cannot find symbol error: cannot find symbol import com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookAdapter;

Tags: react-native

[image]
I am getting this error "cannot find symbol import com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookAdapter" while trying to execute app in android studio`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is cause by `'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.12.0.0'`.
Google removed 2 classes: `FacebookAdapter` and `FacebookExtras` on version `6.12.0.0`.
I don't know why they are remove them (maybe replace for a new API or maybe just a mistake). You can temporary resolve this by downgrade the package version to `6.11.0.0`.
[image: com.google.ads.mediation:facebook]

Comment: still same error show